# Dash Plotly - dbc.Button n_clicks callback not working

Tags: python, button, plotly-dash

So my `n_clicks` property of a (Dash Bootstrap Component) `dbc.Button` is not incrementing when I click on it.

**BUTTON CODE**

`save_button = dbc.Button("Save", id="save_new_item_button", className="btn btn-danger")`

This button is used to saved the data that I type in a model to a SQLITE3 database.

**CALLBACK FUNCTION**

```
@app.callback(
    Output("modal_add_new", "is_open"),
    Output("add-new-status", "children"),
    [
        Input("add_new_item_btn", "n_clicks"),
        Input("close_modal_add_new", "n_clicks"),
        Input("save_new_item_button", "n_clicks"),
        Input("name-row", "value"),
        Input("description-row", "value"),
        Input("price-row", "value"),
        Input("unit-row", "value"),
        Input("limited-row", "value"),
        Input("stock-row", "value"),
        Input("active-row", "value"),
        Input("image-row", "filename"),
        Input("image-row", "contents"),
    ],
    [State("modal_add_new", "is_open")],
)
def toggle_modal(add, close, save, name, desc, price, unit, limited, stock, active, filename, content, is_open):

    # CONNECT TO SQLITE3 DATABASE
    connection = sql.connect(DATABASE)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    print(save)

    if add or close:
        return not is_open, ""
    if save:
        print(is_open)
        if name is None or len(name) > 20:
            return is_open, "Enter a correct name."
        if desc is None:
            return is_open, "Enter a correct description."
        if price is None or price <= 0:
            return is_open, "Enter a number bigger than 0 in price field."
        if unit is None:
            return is_open, "Enter a correct Basic Unit."
        if limited != "yes" or limited != "no" or limited is None:
            return is_open, "Enter 'yes' or 'no' in limited field."
        if stock is None or stock < 0:
            return is_open, "Enter a number equal or bigger than 0 in stock field."
        if active != "yes" or active != "no" or active is None:
            return is_open, "Enter 'yes' or 'no' in active field."
        if filename is None or content is None:
            return is_open, "Invalid image file"
        else:
            for n, d in zip(filename, content):
                save_file(n, d)
            add_product(cursor, connection, name, price, unit, limited, stock, active, filename, desc)
            print("added")
            return is_open, "Added successfully"

    return is_open, ""
```

I can't understand what I am doing because the button next to it (close in `toggle_modal()`) works perfectly.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem likely stems from id="save_new_item_button" being duplicated across multiple html/dbc/dcc components.

Even if it's not rendered in your layout, as long as Dash registers components with duplicated ids on load, "n_clicks" (or "value" for that matter) properties will always take 'None' values in the @app.callback.